# Fancybox 2 set width and height from parameter

Tags: jquery, fancybox, height, width

I have an element that onClick gets the width and height from an attribute and then calls the showFanceBox() function.

```
function showFanceBox(fWidth, fHeight, path){

    console.log(fWidth, fHeight, path)
    $.fancybox({
        width           : fWidth,
        height          : fHeight,
        closeClick      : false,
        padding         : 0,
        type            : "iframe",
        href            : 'games/'+path+'/index.html'
    });
}
```

the console.log returns the parameters perfectly ex: 800 300 p04e1

The fancybox opens the link but the size is not right, it goes to full screen or somthing.
Can someone explain to me what em I missing? Why does't "**path**" variable work but the "**fWidth**" and the "**fHeight**" doeasn't?

Comment: Hmm have you tried options: `autoScale: false` and `autoDimensions: false`?

Comment: your code works perfectly http://jsfiddle.net/vkWQU/ maybe just adding `fitToView: false` .... also check that you are not missing fancybox css file

Comment: added autoScale: false autoDimensions: false , doeasn't make any difference, And css are included otherwise it wouldn't go ontop.

Comment: Every time i let the default values for width and height it scales it accordingly , but when i place a value it makes it fullscreen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so a good night sleep makes a difference :) 
If any one of you have the same problem it is because your variable is a String and not an Int
Adding these before the fancybox will fix the script:

```
fWidth = parseInt (fWidth);
fHeight = parseInt (fHeight);
```

Comment: maybe you were passing the parameters like `showFanceBox("400", "200", "some url")` but integer values go without quotes like `showFanceBox(400, 200, "some url")` http://jsfiddle.net/vkWQU/